# Starting the stem-plot from zero instead of one on the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a function using the filter feature in MATLAB. I would like my graph to start at zero but it is starting at one for some reason. Here is the code I have:

```
x2 = zeros(1,20);
x2(1) = 1;

A = [1 -0.9];
B = [1 0];

y3 = filter(B,A,x2);

figure(3);

stem(y3);
```

I have also added a screenshot of my graph.

[image]

How can I get the first impulse to start at zero instead of one?

Comment: specify both the x and y axis values. `stem(0:numel(y3)-1,y3);` When `x` axis values are not specified, these are automatically taken as integers from 1 to number of y terms

Comment: Thank you so much Sardar Usama! That fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Specify both the x and y axis values.

```
stem(0:numel(y3)-1, y3);
```

When x-axis values are not specified, these are automatically taken as integers from 1 to number of y terms. Read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html) for further details and examples.